# Is it possible to install a different wordpress installation in a subdirectory?

Tags: multisite, directory, installation

What I'm trying to say is, I have this wordpress site called www.mysite.com which is a one pager site that only contains static pages and I want to install a new wordpress installation called shop and use it as an ecommerce page. So it will be called www.mysite.com/shop and shop will be a completely different installation. Is this possible and How am I going to do this?

and on the nav bar I'll have something like, Home - About Us - Contact - Shop.

and Shop will automatically direct to the new installation?

Answer (score -1):

yes, It is Possible.

Create a New folder in your Web-directory like /shop and Install wordpress in there.

Thanks